# I keep on getting an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "exit"

Tags: java, exception, jgrasp

My code looks like this. It compiles fine and runs fine until I enter "exit" in the JOptionPane window. "exit" is meant for the code to stop and display the average, min, max, and range. When I enter exit it prints

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "exit"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
at Loop2.main(Loop2.java:41)



import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Loop2
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        float max = 0;//Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        float min = 0;//Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        float sum = 0;
        float num = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float average = 0;
        float range = 0;
        String userInput;

        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter a value. " , null);
        num = Float.parseFloat(userInput);

        if (!userInput.equals("exit"))
        {
        num = Float.parseFloat(userInput);
        min = num;
        max = num;

        }//end if

        while (!userInput.equals("exit") )
        {
            sum = sum + num;
            count++;

        if( num > max )
        {
           max = num;
        } 

        if( num < min )
        {
           min = num;
        }

        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter a value. " , null);
        num = Float.parseFloat(userInput);

        } //end while

        average = (sum) / (count);

        System.out.println( "Average: " + average );

        range = (max) - (min);

        System.out.println( "Range: " + range );

        System.out.println( "Minimum value: " + min );

        System.out.println( "Max value: " + max );  
   }
}
```

Comment: You're passing "exit" into `Float.parseFloat()`, which is throwing the `Exception`.

Comment: The exception message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to convert "exit" into a float, which isn't possible. You should check for the "exit" string before casting to float

Answer (score 1):

First, you parse float, and then you check if it is "exit", and then parse float again:

```
userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter a value. " , null);
num = Float.parseFloat(userInput);

if (!userInput.equals("exit"))
{
    num = Float.parseFloat(userInput);
```

Comment: He should remove the first `num = Float.parseFloat(userInput);` call...but he should also probably have some other handling in case the user types in some other word.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I focused on the specific case mentioned in the quesion.

Comment: Right, was just adding that in!

Comment: I cant figure out how to make exit work. I tried replacing exit with "0000" and the program worked. I just need the word exit for this project.

Comment: As [Jackmerius Tacktheritrix](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4987943/jackmerius-tacktheritrix) wrote, just remove first `num = Float.parseFloat(userInput);`. You just need to parse float only inside IF statement (`if (!userInput.equals("exit"))`).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse 'exit' as a number, simply remove the first call to Float.parseFloat, as you are calling this if the user hasn't typed exit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to parse "exit" to a float before checking for exit.

`num = Float.parseFloat(userInput);
        if (!userInput.equals("exit"))
        {`

Try this instead:

```
  if (!userInput.equals("exit")){
     num = Float.parseFloat(userInput);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still returns an exception. If i replace "exit" with "0000" the whole program works. Is there anyway to make exit work instead of "0000". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Float.parseFloat(string);
```

The parseFloat method returns the exception NumberFormatException if the string does not contain a parsable float. Check your string input.